# Get File size sore it in shared preference

Tags: android, filesize

Can someone help me to get SDcard file size and store in shared preference:
I can not figure out how to read URL_FileSize and compare with that already store it in shared preference. if its URL file bigger then store file size download if not ignore..

EDIT:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


public static final String PREFS_UPDATE = "sysupdate";

public static final String external_sd = Environment
        .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
public static final File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
public static final String sdcardBaseDir = sdCard.getAbsolutePath();
public static final String externalPath = "/Android/data/com.example/";
public static final String csvFileName = "rsconfig.csv";

public static int file_size;

public static final String url = "http://www.example.com/appconfig.csv";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_UPDATE, 0);
    file_size = prefs.getInt("fileSize", 0);

    try {
        URL link = new URL(url);
        URLConnection urlConnection = link.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        int link_file_size = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        if (file_size < link_file_size) {
            // Download it

            File filenew = new File(sdcardBaseDir + externalPath
                    + csvFileName);
            int file_size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(filenew
                    .length()));
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
            editor.putLong("fileSize", file_size);
            editor.commit();

            startDownload();
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void startDownload() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion and comments...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get the file size of the file that is available at the `url`. For that you might have to do something like this in your code.

```
URL link = new URL(url);
URLConnection urlConnection = link.openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();
int link_file_size = urlConnection.getContentLength();
if (file_size < link_file_size){
      //Download it
}
else{
    //Ignore the file
    }
```

Comment: thanks Antrromet for your replay...i can not acess to my work right now i will test later..

Comment: Dear Antrromet I have updated my code with your code can you look at if i done something wrong? because when i run no file download it...

Comment: What is the value of the link_file_size? If its 0, then your server is not configured to return the file size. If that is the case then you should ask the server people for the same.